# How to install a Lisp compiler?

Tags: software-installation

How can I install a Lisp (or Common Lisp) compiler in raspberry pi? I try `sudo apt-get install lisp`, `sudo apt-get install common-lisp` and can't find any related package. I also try to use `lisp` directly to verify if raspbian (is the system which I pretend to install the compiler) comes with any Lisp compiler.

Comment: Emacs? Scheme? Clojure?

Comment: Clojure runs on a java virtual machine and it implicates install the jvm on raspberry. But clojure have some notables differences such a syntax rules. I'm searching some related to the original lisp.

Comment: The answer depends on what you need it for.  Scheme is good for learning.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

For Common Lisp there are quite a few free implementations available. The following are working on the Raspberry Pi  or similar ARM-based computers with GNU/Linux:

Free:

- [Clozure CL](http://ccl.clozure.com) (CCL), 32bit, fast/compact native code compiler
- [SBCL](http://www.sbcl.org), fast native code compiler
- [Embedded Common Lisp](https://common-lisp.net/project/ecl/) (ECL), uses a C compiler for code generation
- [GNU CLISP](http://www.clisp.org), small footprint due to its own virtual machine
- [ABCL](https://common-lisp.net/project/armedbear/), runs on top of the JVM (the Java Virtual Machine)
- [GNU Common Lisp](http://www.gnu.org/software/gcl/) (GCL), uses a C compiler for code generation

Commercial/proprietary:

- [Allegro CL](https://franz.com/products/allegrocl/), 64bit
- [LispWorks](http://www.lispworks.com/products/lispworks.html), 32bit and 64bit, fast native code compiler with GUI toolkit supporting GTK+ and integrated development environment

For all above [GNU Emacs](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/) (the editor), [SLIME](https://common-lisp.net/project/slime/) (the Lisp development environment extension for Emacs) and [Quicklisp](https://www.quicklisp.org/) (a software library manager for Common Lisp) will provide a useful development environment.

If you want to learn Lisp programming, I recommend to use SBCL. It's freely available, widely used and has the best compiler. The SBCL compiler can give a lot of feedback and warns about many problems (like syntax errors and undefined variables/functions).

**Example Setup with Clozure Common Lisp**

I've described how you get and set up Clozure Common Lisp together with Emacs/SLIME/Quicklisp for use on a Raspberry Pi and similar computers:

**http://lispm.de/ccl**

Clozure CL is a full featured Common Lisp implementation with a quick compiler which generates native ARM code. You'll also get fast start up times and a relatively small memory footprint.

Actually the page above was running on a Raspberry Pi. It currently runs on an ODROID - which is also ARM-based and also runs Ubuntu GNU Linux. It uses LispWorks and a lisp-based web server. I serve it from home with a VDSL connection, so just try it later if it is not available...

Comment: I can confirm that Rainer's method works, as I followed his instructions successfully a few months ago to get CCL up and running. CLisp also installs. There is no successful arm port of SBCL so far though.

Answer (score 7):

Use `apt-cache` when searching, e.g.:

```
apt-cache search lisp
```

Linux and lisp actually go way back (some folks at GNU are fond of it and it is fundamental to things like emacs and gimp), so you'll see a decent list.  I'm not a user myself, but the actual implementation on raspbian appears to be **[clisp](http://www.clisp.org/)**; `apt-get install clisp` should get you what you want.

Comment: Thanks! it's just what I need. Sorry, I can't vote-up you (my reputation is insufficient).

Answer (score 0):

[Clisp](http://www.clisp.org/) is available from the Raspbian repositories and is easily installable with

```
sudo apt-get install clisp
```

I would also recommend installing [Emacs](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/) as a powerful Lisp-aware text editor and install [Slime](https://common-lisp.net/project/slime/) to help with running the Common Lisp interpreter (the clisp REPL) from within Emacs.

```
sudo apt-get install emacs slime
```

Another alternative available from the repositories is [SBCL](http://www.sbcl.org/), an even more powerful Lisp compiler, although it's error messages and debugger maybe a hair less user friendly then Clisp, at least for a newbie. It is fast becoming the standard Lisp compiler for most Lisp users.

Debian (and therefore Raspbian) takes care of installing Slime and integrating it with Emacs and clisp so entering `M-x slime` within emacs will start a REPL within emacs. If you are not comfortable with Emacs, I would suggest starting with the Emacs tutorial, hit `Ctrl-h t` once inside Emacs; in other words hit the `Ctrl` and `'h'` keys simultaneously followed by the `'t'` key alone and that should launch the built in Emacs tutorial. Enjoy.

Answer (score 0):

I am making an interpreter compiler for ISLisp.
As it is small, it works lightly with Raspberry pi.
Check out the youtube video. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KfrRyKMcTw8&t=37s
Published on github. https://github.com/sasagawa888/eisl